# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql' using Jupyter / Panda

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, pymysql

Need a Help from somebody out there!

> The errors mentioned below occurs in jupyter when executing

```
Import pymysql
```

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
last)  in 
----> 1 import pymysql

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

> and when Executing

```
create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/pandas_tutorial')

ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-2-751a940a98c4> in <module> ----> 1 engine = 
 sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/pandas_tutorial')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py in create_engine(*args, **kwargs) 
477 strategy = kwargs.pop("strategy", default_strategy) 
478 strategy = strategies.strategies[strategy] 
--> 479 return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs) 
480 
481 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py in create(self, name_or_url, **kwargs) 
85 if k in kwargs: 
86 dbapi_args[k] = pop_kwarg(k) 
--->    87 dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args) 
88 
89 dialect_args["dbapi"] = dbapi 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\pymysql.py in dbapi(cls) 
60 @classmethod 
61 def dbapi(cls): ---> 
62 return __import__("pymysql") 
63 
64 def is_disconnect(self, e, connection, cursor): 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

OS & Tools:

```
Windows 10
Jupyter 6.0.1
Python 3.7.4
Pandas 3
```

list of Packages installed:

```
mysql       0.0.2
mysqlclient 1.4.6    
pip         20.0.2   
PyMySQL     0.9.3  using "pip install pymysql"   
setuptools  41.2.0
SQLAlchemy  1.3.13 using "pip install sqlalchemy"
```

Comment: Hi! Please check if you are using the same python executable as the one where you installed your package by `import sys
sys.executable`.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Joseph. I tried to execute the above statement in Jupiter notepad. it gave me the error:File "<ipython-input-301-b1ab7f602698>", line 1
    import sys sys.executable
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @AsadIqbal Did you manage to solve this problem? I just ran into it today :(